# Flexbox overlapping flex item in IE 11

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

[Screenprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka994.png)

The parent container has display: flex . Also the container has horizontal scroll enabled. Flex items have a specific width too.
Its works perfectly on all other browsers Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Edge.

Following is my code
**HTML**

```
.card-body.fav-card-container(ng-if='availableFavoriteApps()') #custom-akam-apps.contacts.row.fav-container .col-sm-4.col-md-2.col-lg-2.col-xs-6(ng- repeat="app in appPage.favoriteApps | filter:{name:appPage.searchQuery} track by app.id") .card-group.fav-card
```

**CSS**

```
.fav-container { display: flex; overflow-x: auto; padding: 12px 0; } .fav-card { min-width: 180px; }
```

In IE 11, the flex items are getting overlapped. Please refer the attached screenshot.
Can someone advise here?

Comment: Can you upload your code ?

Comment: HTML:
`.card-body.fav-card-container(ng-if='availableFavoriteApps()')
   #custom-akam-apps.contacts.row.fav-container
       .col-sm-4.col-md-2.col-lg-2.col-xs-6(ng-repeat="app in appPage.favoriteApps | filter:{name:appPage.searchQuery} track by app.id")
         .card-group.fav-card`

CSS:
`.fav-container {
   display: flex;
   overflow-x: auto;
   padding: 12px 0;
}`
`.fav-card {
    min-width: 180px;
  }`

Comment: Could see that IE11 has partial support for flex.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-ms-flexbox` and `-webkit-flex` in `.fav-container`. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
.fav-container { 
  display: flex; 
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  overflow-x: auto; 
  padding: 12px 0; 
} 

.fav-card { 
  min-width: 180px; 
}
```

Comment: Had tried all these combinations. But didn't help. Thats why thought of taking communities help.

Comment: Above code snippet works fine on IE11 at my end. Please share your complete code in the fiddle to more clarification. Thanks